# How to align text in inkscape figures (when converted to .pdf_tex files)?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Apologies if this has been already asked (I couldn't find a precise question):

- I use Inkscape to draw figures
- I draw a box, and within it a text. I *align* the text to the center of the box both horizontally and vertically.
- I save the figure as "save as"-->PDF-->[checked "Omit text in pdf and create LaTeX file" option]
  [image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q10jm.png)
- I press OK to save.

Outcome:

- The text is completely un-alligned with the figures. E.g., a box with a text, may have the text appearing outside the box altogether.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: as of now my understanding is that this is not possible in most cases, except for extremely ad hoc methods.

Conclusion: I am doubtful that inkscape can integrate well with latex.
I moved to LatexDraw, a java program that is much less fancy, but much easier to learn and can integrate latex in it (and shows the resulting figure after the latex compilation).